# Error: Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float32 and Byte

Tags: google-earth-engine, satellite-image

I'm new to use Google Earth Engine and trying to export satellite image dataset to my google drive folder. But I'm getting the error below.

Error: Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float32 and Byte.

This is my code.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
              .filterDate('2021-04-01', '2021-11-10')
              .filterBounds(roi)
              .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
              .first()
              
var fires = dataset.select('T21');
var firesVis = {
  min: 325.0,
  max: 400.0
};
Map.addLayer(fires.clip(roi), firesVis, 'California Fires 2021');
Map.centerObject(roi,15);

// Export data to google drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image : fires,
  description : 'California_wildfires_2021',
  scale : 30,
  region : roi,
  maxPixels : 1e13
})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Also please let me know how to convert the tiff files to images(png/jpeg/jpg).

Comment: Your code worked for me

Comment: Ohh Is it? Do we have to make any settings in the GEE editor?

Comment: No, but I don't know what roi is so I had to guess

Answer (score 0):

Now, add any shapefile or roi and try it.
In the middle of the code their I had used max(),there you can use mean(), median() and min() etc.,

here is the code:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS').filter(
ee.Filter.date('2021-04-01', '2021-11-10'));
var fires = dataset.select('T21').max().clip(shp);
var firesVis = {
  min: 325.0,
  max: 400.0,
  palette: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
};
Map.centerObject(shp, 6);
Map.addLayer(fires, firesVis, 'Fires');

// Export data to google drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image : fires,
  description : 'California_wildfires_2021',
  scale : 1000,
  region : shp,
  maxPixels : 1e13
});
```